# When is a boolean function considered "affine"

Tags: boolean-logic

Like the title says my Question is following: When is a boolean function affine? I need this to check if some boolean function(s) make up for an adequat set.

I found following definition:

> affine if f(x1,...,xn) = c0 ⊕ c1x1 ⊕···⊕ cnxn for some c0,...,cn ∈{0,1}

But i don't really get it. Is there some simple way e.g reading it out of a truth table for a small function?

Consider f(x,y) = x ⊕ y

```
+------------+
|x  y  |  f  |
|1  1  |  0  |
|1  0  |  1  |
|0  1  |  1  |
|0  0  |  0  |
+------------+
```

What does f(x1...xn) mean in this content?

And what is that c0...cn respectively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [common definition](https://www.hindawi.com/archive/2013/270424/) is:
[image]

Basically, the inputs are summed up with exclusive or, unless the respective coefficient is false. In your notation, "c0" will invert the function value.

To check for a function with few inputs, you can make use of the function table. In your example:

```
x1 x2
x  y  f
1  1  0  =  c2 ⊕ c1 ⊕ c0
1  0  1  =       c1 ⊕ c0
0  1  1  =  c2      ⊕ c0
0  0  0  =            c0
```

From the final row, it follows that c0 must be 0.

Inserted "c0=0" in row 2 and row 3, we get "c1=1" and "c2=1".

The first row turns out to be correct. Therefore "x ⊕ y" is in fact *affine*.
In this simple case, this could have been said directly by inspection without truth-table.